# Jquery remove first duplicate id through loop

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to remove all the first duplicate id in a loop.

```
$("#div2 #column3").each(function() {
   var $ids = $("#div2 #column3");
   if (("#div2 #column3").length) {
         $ids.first().remove();
     }
});
```

Here is a fiddle with what I tried. https://jsfiddle.net/qm89a1cf/5/

I'm trying to have as result:

```
hi
hello
yo
hi
hello
yo
hi
hello
yoo
```

***Note:-*** I knew that HTML structure is incorrect (as same `ids` multiple times appear inside HTML), But i am unable to correct it, ***because HTML comming through another person***)

Comment: If are duplicating IDs, I would suggest that you will have bigger problems. You should probably consider using classes for such applications.

Comment: Are you asking how to use jQuery to fix illegal HTML?

Comment: ID be unique in HTML.

Comment: Question seems really confusing. Clearly state your issue.

Comment: yeah I totally know that this html is broken but I have to do with that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because jQuery needs clean HTML to work. Cleaning bad HTML using jQuery is a non-sense. The problem OP has is then too broad.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette ah ok t.t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Important:- As others are commented you have to clean Your HTML.(MAKE `id` unique-per-element, or use `class`).***

A work-around for current scenario is:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div#div2").each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().length > 0) {
      if ($(this).children('#column3').length > 1) {
        $(this).children('#column3:first').remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div2">

  <div id="column1">hi</div>
  <div id="column2">hello</div>
  <div id="column3">5</div>
  <div id="column3">yo</div>

</div>

<div id="div2">

  <div id="column1">hi</div>
  <div id="column2">hello</div>
  <div id="column3">5</div>
  <div id="column3">yo</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <div id="column1">hi</div>
  <div id="column2">hello</div>
  <div id="column3">yoo</div>
</div>
```

***Working Fiddle:-*** https://jsfiddle.net/p8tpyj0j/

***Note:-*** As i said work-arround for current scenario, i can't assure you that same code work for different HTML.

Comment: @LoveDev  please take care of all other people comments. They told for your better sake.

Comment: yeah I know, but actually I can't change the html, I have to deal with it. :/ I know that ID should be unique! And when I saw that code I was also schoked.. but I can't change..

Comment: @LoveDev  ok, no issue, but you can ask that person to take care of the comments what others said here. he/she will get better idea HOW to create CORRECT HTML (you can convey the comments to him or this answer link to check)

Comment: yeah I will try to tell him..  thanks again! And yeah I totally agree that this post shouldn't be upvote because it's a particular -non recommended- case. ^^'